# Sync photos between iPhone and OS X

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos.app, photos, photo-stream

I want to import photos I made on an iPhone to a MacBook so that I can, firstly, keep a copy on the phone (to be able to quickly show photos to someone), and, secondly, to be able to delete photos from one device and get those photos deleted on the other. In other words, I want the photos synchronised between these devices.

I tried to:

- Import photos with iPhoto via cable — it works, but the photos are not synced, just copied;
- Enable iCloud Photo Library (Beta) option in Settings — iCloud — Photos on the iPhone. This way all photos get uploaded to iCloud, and I can see them in the icloud.com web-interface, but I can't see them in iPhoto. I tried enabling My Photo Stream and Automatic Import in iPhoto as suggested by Apple docs on their website, but that didn't help — iPhoto still shows "No photos" in iCloud source;
- Use Photo Stream (without beta iCloud Photo Library) — still no photos in iPhoto.

I think I may have misunderstood something — in my opinion photo synchronisation should be a somewhat simpler task. I am also quite new to Apple stuff and thus I'm a bit confused with all these different terms; I am more accustomed to simple file operations as on Linux and pre–synchronisation era Windows operating systems.

What would be my options please? For now, I'm more inclined to ditch the whole idea of synchronisation and just copy my photos to the laptop (and maybe delete the sources on the phone).

I am using an iPhone 5s with iOS 8.1.3 and a MacBook Pro Retina mid 2014 with OS X Yosemite 10.10.2.

Comment: Look at Photosync.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one iPhoto doesn't have iCloud Photo Library implemented into it. There has been a new update to OS X that adds a new photos app, update your Mac using the Mac App Store ad then also update your iPhone to iOS 8.3 ad enable iCloud Photo Library. Everything will be synced: Edits,  deletes and additions.